# Send a html table styled with css functions without needing to send the css file

Tags: css, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe, which has been styled with a css funcion

```
function df_style.css

.mystyle {
font-size: 11pt; 
font-family: Arial;
border-collapse: collapse; 
border: 1px solid silver;

}

.mystyle td, th {
padding: 5px;
}

.mystyle tr:nth-child(even) {
background: #E0E0E0;
}

.mystyle tr:hover {
background: yellow;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

I then style my dataframe and write it as a html file

```
html_string = '''
<html>
  <head><title>Lista de Partidos Completa</title></head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="df_style.css"/>
  <body>
    {}
  </body>
</html>.
'''


bm=html_string.format(finalframe.to_html(classes='mystyle'))
```

The problem being, when I send my html file to another computer, it loses its styling, as it is in the css file. I have been told I need to put that file in a style tag, but I don't know how to do it, nor any other method that could be as effective.

Summary: I want to send a html table file without losing its styling and without needing to send another different file

Comment: insert your style in between the `<style>/* your styles */</style>` tag in `<head>` instead linking a CSS file, it will be part of your html file.

Comment: Without modifying my code from the css function?

Comment: Your CSS has to be inserted into your html_string in between the style tags instead creating another file